# Does right to work or other immigration related provisions affect migrants' ability to volunteer with charities?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, immigration

Right to work scheme I think extends to apprenticeships and internships but does it or anything similar apply to volunteering at charities?

Comment: Can you give some more detail, please.  Although there's the [Charity Worker Visa](https://www.gov.uk/temporary-worker-charity-worker-visa), a proper answer will depend on the migrant's immigration status, and any conditions imposed by the Home Office. e.g. Indefinite Leave to Remain and EU Settled Status should impose no (relevant) restrictions but Limited Leave to Remain and an Asylum Claim may do.